# How to calculate mean form multiple csv files?

Tags: python, csv

I have 100 CSV files with a similar format and they have only two values of mean and std:

file1.csv

```
mean  0.21  
std   0.54
```

I need to extract every mean and std from each CSV file and calculate the total means like: (mean[mean1,mean2,..]) and (mean[std1,std2,..]). It is hard to go manually every file one by one and copy their mean and std and then calculate mean of all.

Comment: You want python solution only? Are you using linux?

Comment: I want a python solution. Yes I am using Linux (mac )

Answer (score 2):

If `file1.csv` through `file100.csv` are all in the same directory, you can use this Python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

N = 100
mean_sum = 0
std_sum = 0
for i in range(1, N + 1):
    with open(f"file{i}.csv") as f:
        mean_sum += float(f.readline().split(",")[1])
        std_sum += float(f.readline().split(",")[1])

print(f"Mean of means: {mean_sum / N}")
print(f"Mean of stds: {std_sum / N}")
```

This is assuming they are actually formatted as CSV files, with comma separators. If the fields are just separated by spaces, as in your code snippet, then use `.split()` instead of `.split(",")`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the names of the files are in `your_files`:

```
means, deviations = [], []
for file_name in your_files:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lines = (float(line.split()[1]) for line in f)
        means.append(next(lines))
        deviations.append(next(lines))
```

Then you can calculate the mean using the ordinary formula.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call this a caveman approach, but it should work:

```
import os
means = []
stds = []
for file in os.listdir():
    if not file.startswith('file'):
        continue
    mean, std = [float(l.split()[1]) for l in open(file).readlines()]
    means.append(mean)
    stds.append(std)

print('mean mean', sum(means)/len(means))
print('mean stds', sum(stds)/len(stds))
```

---

Testing:

```
$ echo "mean 0.21
> std 0.54" > file1.csv
$ echo "mean 0.23
> std 0.56" > file2.csv
$ python -q
>>> import os
>>> means = []
>>> stds = []
>>> for file in os.listdir():
...     if not file.startswith('file'):
...         continue
...     mean, std = [float(l.split()[1]) for l in open(file).readlines()]
...     means.append(mean)
...     stds.append(std)
... 
>>> print('mean mean', sum(means)/len(means))
mean mean 0.22
>>> print('mean stds', sum(stds)/len(stds))
mean stds 0.55
```

Comment: lddon thanks for your comment. I feed the input files and when i ma running, i ma getting error as ```ZeroDivisionError: division by zero``` on line ```print('mean mean', sum(means)/len(means))```

Comment: Check the format of your files to make sure they match exactly the format that your question has in it. If they have additional leading spaces, for instance, then you will need to edit your question.